# AWS Cognito Session Tokens and API Gateway Templates

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito Federated Identities to map tokens from arbitrary identity providers to Session Tokens and Temporary Credentials.  But it is critical that we obtain the issuer and subject claims for each of these identities within either the API Gateway or our target micro services.

To this end, I am trying to extract the issuer and subject claims from an AWS Session Token using API Gateway Mapping Templates.  All APIs are signed with AWS Signature Version 4.  But to be clear, very few of our identities are coming from AWS Cognito User Pools, but from various trusted identity providers we have configured in AWS Cognito Federated Identities.

I am referring to the following page for instruction:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

What I have seen thus far:

- $context.authorizer.claims.property: only useful for identities from Cognito User Pools
- $context.identity.cognitoIdentityId: gets the Cognito Federated Identities key for an identity

Am I missing something?

- Is it possible to extract issuer/subject from Mapping Template Context for an arbitrary identity?
- Alternatively, is it possible to query Cognito Federated Identities for issuer/subject using a CognitoIdentity obtained via $context.identity.cognitoIdentityId

Feedback is much appreciated,
Thanks,
Randy